# Replacing NAs in R with condition to zero

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have this dataframe called `mydf`. I need to replace the `NAs` in mydf with (zero) '`0`' if meets this condition: if number, `NA`; or `NA`, number is present; then `NA` has to be `0` else every other NA's remains as is. The result is shown below.

mydf

```
A     B     C
1,3   1,NA  NA,1
NA,4  0,0   5,NA
NA    NA,NA NA,6
```

result

```
   A     B     C
   1,3   1,0  0,1
   0,4  0,0   5,0
   NA   NA,NA 0,6
```

Comment: Those do not look like `NA` but like character strings with `"NA"` characters.

Comment: @SabDeM Those are na in my matrix, I need to get rid of these suckers.

Comment: My guess is that you could get rid of them while creating these strings in the first place.

Comment: I have at least 1000 lines long code and now I don't know where these suckers came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this task.

```
mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, sub, pattern = "NA(?=,[0-9])|(?<=[0-9],)NA", 
                 replacement = "0", perl = TRUE)

mydf
#     A     B   C
# 1 1,3   1,0 0,1
# 2 0,4   0,0 5,0
# 3  NA NA,NA 0,6
```

This regex replaces the following matches with `0`: `NA` followed by a comma and a digit, and `NA` preceded by a digit and a comma.

---

For this solution, I assume `mydf` is structured as follows:

```
mydf <- structure(list(A = c("1,3", "NA,4", "NA"), B = c("1,NA", "0,0", 
"NA,NA"), C = c("NA,1", "5,NA", "NA,6")), .Names = c("A", "B", 
"C"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please provide some explanation?

Comment: @MAPK as I've said: they are not `NA` but character stings otherwise regex won't work.

Comment: @SabDeM I think they are character string. I still don't understand why NA is flushed into the data while working with matrix.

Comment: @MAPK that I cannot know, something happened in your previous work and those strings `NA` are been carried since then.